# TypeError: module.Name.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and i am not able to identify/ set up the right props for the following:
      js file    REACT / JS  jest/enzyme

```js
populateModuleDropdown = (moduleList) => {
  let modules = moduleList.map(module => {
    return (
      <DropdownItem key={module.ModuleId} onClick={() => {
      this.props.setTarget(null);
      }}>
      <Link className='full-link'
      onClick={e => {if(this.props.module.moduleId === module.ModuleId){e.preventDefault()}}}
      to={'/'+module.Name.replace(/ /g,'')}>
      {module.Name}
      </Link>
      </DropdownItem>
    )
  })
}
```

I have done some similar files and they all look fine and passing properly, but  unable to identify and fix the following error. Please take a look at 
 let mockmodules

Test.js

```js
configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe(' testing  ', () => {

  let tree;
  let baseProps;
  let mockdefaultData;
  let mockmodule = {
    Name:"test",
    moduleId:{},

    beforeEach(() => {
      module : mockmodule,

      it (' Should render without a Module props',() => {
        baseProps = {
          ...baseProps,
          module: {},
        };
        // code
      });

      it(' Should render with ALL of the props', () => {
        //code

      });
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error means that the object you're referring to, in this case
`module.Name` -- doesn't have a `replace` function. A question to ask that may resolve your question:

1. *What is the intended module you are trying to refer to*? 
   Try doing a `console.log(module.Name)` to see if it is what you are expecting.

If you are attempting to use JS' built-in String replace method, then you would also want to check if the `typeof(module.Name)` is a String. If it is, then follow the documentation for the String replace method here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

If it's not, you may want to backtrack to make sure you have the correct data in place.

Assuming `module.Name` is in fact a String, it's usage would be as follows:

```
module.Name = module.Name.replace(/ /g, '');
```